# ValueProxy's equals() fails because stableId() returns null

Tags: gwt, gxt, requestfactory, json-rpc

Some of my widget code (GXT 3.0) wants to call equals() from a RF-JsonRpc received ValueProxy but it fails because those proxies doesn't have any stableId tag and the equals method implemented in ValueProxyCategory requires it to check if it is comparing the same class types.

http://code.google.com/searchframe#T04cSGC7sWI/trunk/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/impl/ValueProxyCategory.java

Can anyone tell me if the lack of stableId in the received ValueProxy is a bug or i'm making some mistake? Thanks!!!

Can i overwrite the equals implementation for my ValueProxy derived types ? I have an id property on that derived types and i would like to use the id comparation as EntityProxy's equals do.

Comment: Definitely a bug I'd say, still related to the same TODO in the `JsonRpcPayload#processPayload`.

Comment: hell i'm feeling that i'm the first to use RF's JsonRpc hahaha i'm discovering all the bugs... :-/ Do you know how can i override equals() ?? Or maybe i would be able to workaround implementing stableId() for my base ValueProxy class... And BobV seems don't want to improve that code anymore... Thanks Thomas anyway.. again  ;-)

Comment: Google seems to be using it (they fixed some issues earlier this year) but, being used to Protocol Buffer, they probably get info out the proxies and throw them away right in the receiver (i.e. use them as a mean to send/receive data, not as part of the "model")